# ¿Cómo resuelvo esto? ¿porque ya no puedo conectame?

Tags: sql

[image]

Tenia mas de una semana el PC sin apagarlo, hasta ayer que lo reinicie y al ejecutar un programa llamado genexus, ya este daba error. Estos están conectados con `sql` en una misma instancia, utilizo el user **sa** y la clave.

error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: El servidor o la instancia no estan disponibles, incluso podría ser que ya no tienes permisos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez me paso, la solucion fue verificar que el servidor de la BD este activo, prende el SQL, has las conexión y mira si aun persiste el error, podemos descartar que estén mal las contraseñas y el usuario ya que no le has movido nada  ...